# Use custom query for built-in entities in liferay 6.1?

Tags: liferay-6

I have read many posts about creating service layer in liferay. I was able to build a service layer and custom query sample project in eclipse. However, all of the examples I got so far is about adding new entities and performing CRUD actions on those new entities.

I want to ask is it possible to use custom query with built-in entities?. For example, I want to use custom query with `JounalArticle, AssetEntry`, and so on.

If that possible, how can I do that. Please give me some hints or examples.

(I have tried dynamic queries with sub queries but they do not meet my requirements)

Comment: mention your requirements

Comment: It is complicated to describe my project requirements. I just want to know if it is possible to use custom query with built-in entities. If so, some hints or example would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is interested:

In the XXXLocalServiceImpl you can add:

```
    public List<JournalArticle> getArticles(String username) {
         Session session = xxxPersistence.openSession();          
         try {
             String sql = "SELECT * FROM journalarticle ja  WHERE ja.userName like '%"+username+"%'";
             SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
             return query.list();
         }finally {
             session.close();
         }

  }
```

rerun your service builder and you can use form XXXLocalServiceUtil.getArticles("Test Test")

Using service builder: [create database portlets](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/How+to+create+a+database+portlet)